# VB.Net Public Property

Tags: vb.net, properties, private, public

Using code analysis on my program I often get this warning:

> CA1051 : Microsoft.Design : Because field 'Form1.Testcode' is visible outside of its declaring type, change its accessibility to private and add a property, with the same accessibility as the field has currently, to provide access to it.

So it tells me to either change the code from this: `Public Testcode As String`
To this: `Public Property Testcode As String`

Or to this:

```
Private _testcode
 Public Property Testcode As Object
        Get
            Return _testcode
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            _testcode = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

So my question is, what is the difference between the 2 code suggestions.
Is one faster than the other or does it prevent bugs or anything else? I've been using the first code since ever and never had issues with it neither feeling lags or something else.

Saying I want my program to be as fast as possible should I change the Code that I have to the Property code and if yes, which to choose?

Comment: It has nothing to do with speed/performance. `Fields` are usually kept `Private` to the Class, and are accessed using Properties`. This allows for a level of abstraction when retrieving data from the Class. In theory, you can do things like validation within the property before returning a value, or change the field implementation without affecting external classes that access it. Additionally, you can set the access level for you data using a property such as making it ReadOnly for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of properties is that they behave like fields from the outside but like methods from the inside. In fact, once your code is compiled, the getter and setter of your property actually are methods. Java doesn't support properties but even there the convention is to declare a field private and then declare two methods for getting and setting the field value.

Always use properties to expose data publicly. If nothing else, it means that you can bind objects of that type because properties support data-binding while fields do not. It also makes it far less likely that you will need to change the type interface if you need to change the implementation later.

As for how to implement the property, always use an auto-property, i.e. the one-line option, unless you need to add extra code to do things like validation or raise an event. If you write an auto-property, the private field is still created behind the scenes - you can even access it in code - and the compiler still creates the getter and setter methods. In short, prefer this:

```vb
Public Property Data As SomeType
```

to this:

```vb
Private _data As SomeType

Public Property Data As SomeType
    Get
        Return _data
    End Get
    Set
        _data = value
    End Set
End Property
```

An example of a situation that would require the full property is below:

```vb
Private _number As Integer

Property Number As Integer
    Get
        Return _number
    End Get
    Set
        'Validation
        If Value < 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", $"'Number' must not be less than zero.")
        End If

        If _number <> Value Then
            _number = Value

            'Change notification.
            OnNumberChanged(EventArgs.Empty)
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Event NumberChanged As EventHandler

Protected Overridable Sub OnNumberChanged(e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent NumberChanged(Me, e)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> - Is one faster than the other? **No.**
> - Does it prevent bugs or anything else? **Yep.**

In VB, `Public Testcode As String` and `Public Property Testcode As String` look pretty much the same. But let's put the syntax aside, we are speaking about **member variables** and **properties** here.

- **Member variables** are variables you have to use in your classes when they have to "live" as long as the class instance does. It is basically the same as every other variable but without defined context (say the end of a method for example). You'd use them typically to hold kind of a state like whether the user had confirmed a message or anything like that. If this kind of information is important for the logic of your class but not for others, you have a perfect candidate for a member variable.
- **Properties** are not very different here and can technically be used the same. However they are part of an **external interface**. If you have to hold information that is important to your class and to other classes (using your class) as well, you have a perfect candidate for a property. This could be the border color of a button for example. Other classes might set the color by a given design and the button itself needs it to render the border accordingly, of course. Public methods and properties build the interface other parties can interact with. There are some useful answers here on StackOverflow, I'll link them below instead of copying their content.

### Why should we care?

So we're basically talking about encapsulation and [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding). But let's look at that in a more practical example.

Look at your desktop PC. Turn it around and take a look at all the connectors it exposes. This is the public interface of the machine. That's what you as a consumer of the machine can interact with. You see USB ports, HDMI connectors and so on. You don't need to know the internals of the machine to understand where you can connect a mouse to or how you can attach your HDMI-to-DisplayPort adapter. In fact, it would be very confusing if every internal connector would be available to you on the backside of your PC. It would add so much unneeded clutter and it would make things dangerous, too. Because you'd have no chance to know what all these pins and connectors are made for. The hardware manufacturers could not rely on expected conditions because anyone might have messed things up unknowingly from the outside.

Everything you as a consumer can interact with is made public with the interface of standard connectors. Everything the machine needs to work internally is kept away from you to **avoid confusion** about things you don't need to know about and **make sure noone messes with the internal state** the machine has to rely on.

So you could say "lets do everything public because I have no secrets" but in fact that would make the class very **hard to understand** from the outside. It would make it **easy to break** things unknowingly by setting members from external code which your class handles internally and has to rely on.

Another aspect we as software developers have to keep in mind: **Maintainability**. If you have a lot of public members, you are pretty locked when doing refactoring because you'll never know how anyone out there is using them. Keeping a clean interface to the outside is important to be able to change things internally later on.

See:

- [Internal applications - why not make everything public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115266/internal-applications-why-not-make-everything-public)
- [Why shouldn't I be using public variables in my Java class?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176876/why-shouldnt-i-be-using-public-variables-in-my-java-class)

Answer (score 0):

See [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties):

> When you write code for an auto-implemented property, the Visual Basic
> compiler automatically creates a private field to store the property
> variable in addition to creating the associated Get and Set
> procedures.

So using the shorthand notation:

```
Public Property Testcode As String
```

Results in the same code as the longer verbose property, WHEN YOU COMPILE.

There is no difference in the end.